# How to use iTextsharp from Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, pdf, itext

I used iText sharp to generate a PDF file and it works perfectly.  Now I would like to use it on my Silverlight project but when I try to add the references (iTextsharp.dll, itextsharp?pdfa.dll, iTextSharp.xtra.dll) I get this message Box

> You can't add a reference to Itextsharp.xtra.dll as it was built against the silverlight runtime ...

Is it possible to use iText to create a PDF file from Silverlight?  If not how should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about iTextSharp specifically, but although Silverlight is a subset of the .net framework your 3rd-party libraries needs to be built for Silverlight specifically.

If the library you are using does not support Silverlight you could generate your pdf-files on the server and make the client (Silverlight) reference the generated files for download. You could either transfer the file directly to your client and open a save-file-promt, or store it on the server and have your client navigate to the file-url.

Comment: Can you  give me an example please ?

Comment: Well i don't know about the library you are using, or what kind of technology your server i running on. Let's say you are using web-api, then your server-method could look something like this: 

<!-- language: lang-c# -->
[ActionName("GeneratePdf")]


[HttpPost]


public byte[] GeneratePdf([FromBody] long documentId) 


{

 
  //Generate your pdf 


  //Convert to byte array


  return bytes;


}